# Weird value in _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java, jvm

My JDK does not seem to be correct. When I start my computer there is always a environment variable:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
```

This made the JVM failed to launch unless I do export `_JAVA_OPTIONS=""`
I wondered why this problem will appear.

My Operating System is `Debian Jessie`
I have tried Java `7/8/9`, the problem will still exist when computer restarts.

I tried to uninstall JDK and the environment variable still changes after restarting.

Comment: This is not w.r.t the JDK but another software you have installed which uses Java as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is probably set in one of these places:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`

I suggest you examine these files and see where the variable is set, and remove it from there.

Comment: Actually none of the files are setting this variable.